# Gulp/Node: error while loading shared libraries: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block

Tags: node.js, gcc, npm, gulp, g++

Trying to run gulp and getting this output

```
$ gulp
node: error while loading shared libraries: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block
```

From what I have found, this seems to relate to gcc or g++, not sure how it pertains to node or gulp.  Either way I can't seem to run gulp anymore.  Should also mention, this just popped up today.  It was running fine yesterday.

EDIT: seems like it's for all node commands.  Just tried running npm -v to get the version number and it has the same output. Same with node -v

Running CentOS 6.9

Answer (score 3):

The GNU toolchain supports various kinds of TLS, and one of them (the `initial-exec` model) involves what is essentially a fixed offset from the thread control block.  At program startup, the dynamic linker computes all the offsets and makes sure that all threads have sufficient space for all the required thread local variables.

However, with `dlopen`, this does not work in general because it is not possible to move the thread control block around to make room for more thread-local variables.  The current glibc dynamic linker has a heuristic which reserves some space for future `dlopen` calls, but if you load a number of shared objects, each wither their own thread-local variables, this is not enough.

The usual workaround is to use the `LD_DEBUG=files` environment variable (or `strace`) to find relevant shared objects loaded with `dlopen` (unfortunately, the error message you quoted does not provide this information).  After that, you can use the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable to tell the dynamic linker to load them early.  (It is sufficient to do this for the shared object which is `dlopen`ed, its dependencies are processed automatically.)   This has the side effect that the computation at program startup takes into account their TLS needs, and when the `dlopen` call happens later at run time, no additional TLS variables have to be allocated.  However, this approach does not work for all shared objects because it affects symbol lookup and the order in which ELF constructors run.

In the general case, it may be necessary to switch some shared objects to the `global-dynamic` TLS model (which requires recompiling them), or use a glibc build with an increased TLS reserve.  Unfortunately, the reserve cannot currently be set at run time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is all a little complex.  I am just trying to run gulp.  As an end user, what am I supposed to do here?

Comment: As a mere end user, you should probably ask those who supplied the node.js binaries to you to fix them. It is likely to work around this issue.

Comment: Thanks !! SO GREAT !
@BobbyS just prepend `LD_PRELOAD=libjemalloc.so.2` before your command. But Flo gave 2 solutions which is awesome (the dirty LD_PRELOAD worked easyer for me so I did not havve to recompile and install).
You saved my day @FlorianWeimer + I learned the LD_PRELOAD trick. I am Really thankfull !